# Bar overlapping to Y-axis when Panned in the aChartEngine

Tags: android, graph, bar-chart, achartengine, pan

I am working on the application which display the bar graph in it. The bar graph are draw according dynamically values are received to them, the bar graph data is in MB/KB.

**`Code Snippet`** :-

```
private void graphinit(ArrayList<Integer> graphInDataList, ArrayList<Integer> graphOutDataList)
{
    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(graphXMaxLimit);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    // mRenderer.setYAxisMax(100);

    int max = getMaximumNumber(graphInDataList, graphOutDataList);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMax(max);

    double[] limits = new double[] {0, graphXMaxLimit, 0, max};
    mRenderer.setPanLimits(limits);

    mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.3f);

    mRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
    mRenderer.setShowAxes(true);
    mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    mRenderer.setShowLabels(true);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
    mRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);

    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(false);

    mRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(3);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Analysis Duration in mins");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Data in KB");

    // mRenderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);

    // set up the margin to the graph
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 5, 40, 0, 5});

    // mRenderer.setXAxisMin(1);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5);
    // mRenderer.setXAxisMax(60);

    inDataSeries = new XYSeries("InData");      
    for (int i = 0; i < graphInDataList.size(); i++) {      
        inDataSeries.add(i, graphInDataList.get(i));
    }

    outDataSeries = new XYSeries("OutData");        
    for (int i = 0; i < graphOutDataList.size(); i++) {
        outDataSeries.add(i, graphOutDataList.get(i));
    }

    mDataset.addSeries(inDataSeries);
    mDataset.addSeries(outDataSeries);

    if(graphInDataList.size()>0){                   
        right_left=(int) (graphInDataList.size()/60);
    }

    XYSeriesRenderer in_data_renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();     
    in_data_renderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    XYSeriesRenderer out_data_renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();        
    out_data_renderer.setColor(Color.RED);

    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(in_data_renderer);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(out_data_renderer); 

    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent_background));
}
```

**`EDIT :`**

Created in onResume()

```
     if (mChartView == null) {

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_chart);           
        mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, mDataset,
                mRenderer, Type.STACKED);

        Logger.vLog("HistoryDetailScreen", "mChartView : "+mChartView);

        layout.addView(mChartView);

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        boolean enabled = mDataset.getSeriesCount() > 0;

    } else {
        mChartView.repaint();
    }
```

I used graphinit(arrlist1, arrlist2) method in the onCreate().

**`PROBLEM :`**

When we do panning on the bar graph, bar overlapping to the Y-axis.

**`SCREENSHOT Default Screen :`**

[image]

**`SCREENSHOT Panned Screen :`**

[image]

I also set the pan limits for that. What is problem?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think u should use Ist what problem in using Ist?

Comment: @keshav: The bar height crosses the axis lebels marker..

Comment: Increase ur setYAxisMax(); because values are crossing the max.

Comment: Is their any way to automatically increase it?

Comment: u should get max possible  value programmatically

Comment: From where u are getting values to draw bars get max from there.

Comment: Can u show ur complete code with chartview

Comment: Hi! would you like to create custom bar view without using any external library.

Comment: u must have to create you own logic for this issue. In achartengine i also face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me...

```
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5); //for first bar overlaps y-axis
```

Answer (score -1):

You are setting the pan limits correctly, but please note that the bars themselves are not having a width of zero units. Given this, you would have to set the X axis minimum value to something below the minimum X pan limit, for instance `-0.5`.

You can even change the pan limit value at runtime, by listening for zoom events and changing the limits accordingly.

```
mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] {-0.5, graphXMaxLimit, 0, max});

mChartView.addZoomListener(new ZoomListener() {
  public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent e) {
    double currentMinX = mRenderer.getXAxisMin();
    double currentMaxX = mRenderer.getXAxisMax();
    double coef = (graphXMaxLimit + 0.5) / (currentMaxX - currentMinX);
    mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] {-0.5 / coef, graphXMaxLimit, 0, max});
  }

  public void zoomReset() {
    Log.i("Zoom", "Reset");
  }
}, true, true);
```

Comment: Still facing same issue.